# Objective-C creating weak block to check memory release

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have read that If you assign a new object to a weak property, the object will be released after the assignment. Even the warning from the compiler is same.

```
@interface RetainCycleObjCViewController ()
{
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) void (^weakBlock)(void);
@end

@implementation RetainCycleObjCViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 _weakBlock = ^void{
        NSLog(@"Execution inside a weakBlock");
    };

_weakBlock();
}
@end
```

I get the same warning for weakBlock: **Assigning block literal to a weak variable; object will be released after assignment**

But when I execute the _weakBlock() in next line, it still prints the statement. How is it possible? because the newly created block object should have been removed from memory by now, given the 0 reference count?

Comment: It's not going to deallocate until it goes out of scope.. `NSBlock` can be allocated on the stack OR heap (when copied).. but a local block is stack allocated and will only deallocate when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @Brandon's comment is correct, in general, but in this particular example, that block will be a global and will be "live" well beyond that scope.

Answer (score 6):

You aren't actually allocating a block in that code.   The body of the block is all static content;  nothing changes post compilation.

If you do this:

```
    _weakBlock = ^void{
        NSLog(@"Execution inside a weakBlock");
    };
    NSLog(@"%@", [_weakBlock class]);
```

You'll see this:

```
2018-10-21 09:33:48.827423-0500 kdkdkdkds[9367:1777827] __NSGlobalBlock__
```

The compiler recognized the block doesn't capture anything that might change at runtime and, accordingly, created a global static block which will never be allocated.

As @Brandon said in a comment, if you declared a local variable in your scope and caused a stack block to be allocated, that wouldn't go away until the end of the scope.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    void __weak (^_weakBlock)(void);
    int k = 2;
    _weakBlock = ^void{
        NSLog(@"Execution inside a weakBlock (%d)", k);
    };
    NSLog(@"C; %@", [_weakBlock class]);
    NSLog(@"P; %p", _weakBlock);
}
2018-10-21 09:36:31.585458-0500 kdkdkdkds[9392:1780803] C; __NSStackBlock__
2018-10-21 09:36:31.586291-0500 kdkdkdkds[9392:1780803] P; 0x7ffeefbff4c0
```

Now, instance variable assignment changes the rules slightly because you are assigning out of scope.

```
@interface SpongeBob:NSObject
@end

@interface SpongeBob ()
{
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) void (^weakBlock)(void);
@end

@implementation SpongeBob
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        int k = 2;
        _weakBlock = ^void{
            NSLog(@"Execution inside a weakBlock (%d)", k);
        };
        NSLog(@"C; %@", [_weakBlock class]);
        NSLog(@"P; %p", _weakBlock);
    }
    return self;
}
@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[SpongeBob alloc] init];
    }
    return 0;
}

2018-10-21 09:43:39.518545-0500 kdkdkdkds[9480:1787889] C; __NSStackBlock__
2018-10-21 09:43:39.518883-0500 kdkdkdkds[9480:1787889] P; 0x7ffeefbff488
```

Wait.  What?  If that value is really being assigned to the ivar, then this is a ticking time bomb.   So, let's try something:

If we add:

```
- (void)squarePants
{
    NSLog(@"C; %@", [_weakBlock class]);
    NSLog(@"P; %p", _weakBlock);
}
```

And then call it:

```
    SpongeBob *bob = [[SpongeBob alloc] init];
    [bob squarePants];
```

It crashes, as expected, because the stack block is no longer valid as `init`'s scope

(This seems rather mean.   Then again, if you eliminate the warning, the crash goes away.)

Now, if you copy the block on assignment, then the immediate deallocation on assignment *does* kick in:

```
    _weakBlock = [^void{
        NSLog(@"Execution inside a weakBlock (%d)", k);
    } copy];

2018-10-21 09:48:04.295762-0500 kdkdkdkds[9510:1792549] C; (null)
2018-10-21 09:48:04.296167-0500 kdkdkdkds[9510:1792549] P; 0x0
```

Comment: "It crashes, as expected" – do you slander the Obj-C compiler? ;-) I think what your sample shows is a corner-case bug in the compiler. Eons ago now Apple finally said you didn't need to put `copy` on block properties any longer as finally the compiler moves stack blocks to the heap as needed automatically; and assigning to an outer-scope variable is one where the move is needed. Change that weak property to a strong one and the move occurs, leave it as weak and change the assignment to: `void (^block)(void) = ^void{...}; _weakBlock = block;` and the move occurs. (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) When the compiler is figuring out it needs to throw out the warning it should also notice its about to store a stack block reference somewhere it shouldn't and handle it but it misses this corner case. Compiler bug, please report. (And please no-one don't claim this isn't a bug, `localvar temp = a; b = temp;` should have the same observable semantics as `b = a;`)

Comment: "no-one don't" oops :-(

Comment: @CRD I filed a bug when I wrote this capturing that particular corner case.

Comment: Without some serious shenanigans, I don't see an obvious path via which the block gains a strong reference in that code path.   An object?  Sure;  internally, it could create a strong reference to self, causing the weak assignment to remain valid beyond the scope.   I suppose because the stack block survives beyond the weak assignment, one might play shenanigans internally to cause the block to become strongly referenced, but that'd imply a copy which would mean the value weakly assigned is invalid.

Comment: @bbum What I could get out of your answer is, even if it is a weak reference to the block, its life will stay intact until the `init's` scope or `didload` scope in my case. Similar to your `squarePants` method I called the `weakBlock` on another method. But it still executes the NSLog statement without any crash. Am I missing something?

Comment: @nr5 Your block isn't on the stack or heap at all.  That is the first part of this answer's discussion.  Like `@"foo"` constant strings, blocks that are immutable at runtime-- don't capture state-- actually statically compiled and will be valid for the entire app session.